# Java - fun converting a string (4 chars) to int and back

Tags: java, functional-programming

Please don't ask why but I have to store a string (max 4 char) in an integer value (so 4 bytes).

First I wrote this and it works:

```
String value = "AAA";
int sum = IntStream.range(0, value.length())
                   .limit(4)
                   .map(i -> value.charAt(i) << (i * 8))
                   .sum();

System.out.println(sum);
```

I was unable to think a functional solution for the way back.

```
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
while (sum > 0) {
    int ch = sum & 0xff;
    sum >>= 8;
    out.append((char) ch);
}
```

Any idea to write the way back (to "AAA") in a functional way?

Comment: Probably cleaner to do `value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)` and convert to int using a ByteBuffer or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty similar to yours, but maybe will be helpful

```
    String str = IntStream.iterate(sum, s -> s > 0, s -> s >> 8)
            .mapToObj(s -> String.valueOf((char)(s & 0xff)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: No point in using `>>=`. No one's reading `s` after the shift.

Comment: @Michel_T. this solutions seems to be the shorter, but still we need java 9 to have this working

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be:

```
StringBuilder out =
    IntStream.iterate(sum, s -> s > 0, s -> s >> 8)
             .mapToObj(s -> (char) (s & 0xff))
             .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append);

System.out.println(out.toString());
```

Note: I used a three-argument [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) overload that is available starting from Java 9.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be the best way to convert it back to a `String` using streams; your existing `while` loop seems cleaner and may be more performant.  However, there is a streams solution.

```
String result = IntStream.range(0, 4)
        .map(i -> (value >>> 24 - (i * 8)) & 0xFF)
        .dropWhile(i -> i == 0)
        .mapToObj(v -> String.valueOf( (char) v))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

This generates some byte indices, takes the specific byte value, maps it to a `char`, them joins them back to a `String`.  It also drops leading 0 values using the [Java 9+ method `dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.IntPredicate)).

I've corrected this to yield the proper order by adding the "24 -" to grab the most significant byte first.

With a `value` of `0x10101 * 65`, this returns `"AAA"`.  With a `value` of `0x10101 * 65 + 1`, this returns `"AAB"`.

Comment: I don't think you need the "24 -" because the `& 0xFF` should remove the non significant bytes, try this: `final String str1 =  IntStream.range(0, 4)
                                      .map(i -> (value >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF)
                                      .filter(v -> v > 0)
                                      .mapToObj(v -> String.valueOf( (char) v))
                                      .collect(Collectors.joining());;`

Comment: When I tried "AAB" I got "BAA" and had to reverse the bytes with the "24 -".

Comment: very likely you had another problem, check the solution I've posted in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

it's basically a char[4] that's being transferred to an int then back. Realistically I would imagine this would work

```
public static String getStr(int encoded){
    return ((char)(encoded >> 24) + ((char)((encoded >> 16) 0xFF)
            + ((char)((encoded >> 8) & 0xFF) + ((char)((encoded) & 0xFF)
}
```

Comment: But that's not functional way

Comment: well, yes. but the question was about how to do in a functional way i.e. streams, lambda, etc... not with a java function :)

Comment: @freedev What isn't functional? Seems to follow all the paradigms. Unless you want it in the form of a lambda, in which case it's easy enough to convert it into one.

Comment: @MatthewKerian At least you got some feedback as to why they didn't like your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for your contribution. I've found another solution to share with you:

```
String str = IntStream.iterate(sum, s -> s >> 8)
                      .limit(4)
                      .filter(s -> s > 0)
                      .mapToObj(s -> String.valueOf((char) (s & 0xff)))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: I'm really confused. This seems like an awful way to do it, why would you want to do it this way?

Comment: @MatthewKerian I’ve already tried to explain why. Did you haven’t ever heard anything about functional programming? This is all about. The while loop I wrote in the question very likely is the best and easier solution, but does not have the benefits of the functional paradigm. The question is about how to have fun with functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

- Created a string of shift values to go thru the sum.
- Mask off each character.
- Convert to a string.
- And join with a collector.

```java
   String str = IntStream.of(0, 8, 16, 24)
            .mapToObj(i->(char)(sum>>i&0xff)+"")
             .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: I didn’t know that it was possibile have a string adding a char to an empty string